# 1002 - Train request is either invalid or missing required parameters

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Trying to train up my model.  I have 10 pdfs in my "docs2" repo.  I attempt to run the following command in bash shell on Windows Subsystem for Linux and get the 1002 message.  I've changed some digits in the sub keys here for the post but you get the idea.  Anyone have any ideas?

> jhealy@HPZBOOK-DEVFISH MINGW64 ~
>   $ curl -X POST "https://ocrinsights.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/train" -H "Content-T
>   ype: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: b023a97ef64e4fd190f68c5092df7441" --data-ascii "{ \"source\": \""
>   https://ocrinsights.blob.core.windows.net/docs2?st=2019-08-29T17%3A29%3A45Z&se=2019-08-30T17%3A29%3A45Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-0
>   3-28&sr=c&sig=mOwg2xxZBywhZKpDuStlMlh4QZkHnwjCNPiptISEnS8%3D"\"}"
>
> [1] 13348
>
> [2] 17512
>
> [3] 5296
>
> [4] 14296
>
> [5] 17684
>
> [2]   Done                    se=2019-08-30T17%3A29%3A45Z
>
> [3]   Done                    sp=rl
>
> [4]   Done                    sv=2018-03-28
>
> [5]+  Done                    sr=c
>
> jhealy@HPZBOOK-DEVFISH MINGW64 ~
>   $ {"error":{"code":"1002","message":"Train request is either invalid or missing required parameters. Please reference the API reference and retry your request."}}

Similar issue on GitHub, unresolved - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/issues/33

Comment: I wound up just using postman to get past this...

Comment: The same request works in postman but not cURL? That sounds like an encoding issue.

Comment: agree.  for me not worth digging into now, as I should have just used postman from the beginning.  may write an article for the docs on using postman v curl for this.

Comment: I would like to recommend changing the CLI app used.
Ex: try the same command on cmd.exe